# How can I call GC.GetGeneration() using a string as the object name?

Tags: garbage-collection, system.reflection

I'm using Reflection to get all the fields of my class in c#, but now I want to get the GC Generation of each variable in my class. How can I do this?

```
CSkyclass
{
   float time = 0;
} 


Sky = new CSkyclass();


void GetGeneration()
{
   FieldInfo[] FieldArray = typeof(CSkyclass).GetFields(flags);

   foreach(System.Reflection.FieldInfo Field in FieldArray)
   {
      string name = Field.Name; //"time"
      int g = GC.GetGeneration(name); //should = GC.GetGeneration(Sky.time);

   }

}
```

Is this even possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to get the generation of the field's *value*:

```
GC.GetGeneration(field.GetValue(someInstance));
```